# Determine Number of Decimal Place using BigDecimal

Tags: java

I was interested to have the following `getNumberOfDecimalPlace` function:

```
System.out.println("0 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(0));          // 0
System.out.println("1.0 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(1.0));      // 0
System.out.println("1.01 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(1.01));    // 2
System.out.println("1.012 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(1.012));  // 3
System.out.println("0.01 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(0.01));    // 2
System.out.println("0.012 = " + Utils.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(0.012));  // 3
```

May I know how can I implement `getNumberOfDecimalPlace`, by using `BigDecimal`?

The following code doesn't work as expected:

```
public static int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(double value) {
    final BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("" + value);
    final String s = bigDecimal.toPlainString();
    System.out.println(s);
    final int index = s.indexOf('.');
    if (index < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return s.length() - 1 - index;
}
```

The following get printed :

```
0.0
0 = 1
1.0
1.0 = 1
1.01
1.01 = 2
1.012
1.012 = 3
0.01
0.01 = 2
0.012
0.012 = 3
```

However, for case 0, 1.0, it doesn't work well. I expect, "0" as result. But they turned out to be "0.0" and "1.0". This will return "1" as result.

Comment: You are planning your input parameter to be BigDecimal or just internally to use BigDecimal? Cause in your code example input parameter would be just a double.

Comment: I found solutions here useful for implementation of the function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264576/number-of-decimal-digits-in-a-double

Comment: Which "Utils" is this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This code:

```
int getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    String string = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
    int index = string.indexOf(".");
    return index < 0 ? 0 : string.length() - index - 1;
}
```

... passes these tests:

```
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("0.001")), equalTo(3));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("0.01")), equalTo(2));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("0.1")), equalTo(1));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("1.000")), equalTo(0));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("1.00")), equalTo(0));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("1.0")), equalTo(0));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("1")), equalTo(0));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("10")), equalTo(0));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("10.1")), equalTo(1));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("10.01")), equalTo(2));
assertThat(getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(new BigDecimal("10.001")), equalTo(3));
```

... if that is indeed what you want. The other replies are correct, you have to use BigDecimal all the way through for this rather than double/float.

Comment: This is the only right answer on the page.  Why?  Because @Robert uses stripTrailingZeros() to distinguish those decimal places that are truly significant.  Well done, Robert.

Comment: @Robert Atkins **warning**, gives me 1 with "0.0", should be 0.

Comment: you can return 0 when `scale() <= 0` or `signum() == 0`, you can also avoid some toString()-thing that way.

Comment: Can't you `bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().scale()`?

Answer (score 62):

Combining [Turismo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296352/14731), [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4592016/14731) and [user1777653's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26938787/14731) answers, we've got:

```
int getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    return Math.max(0, bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().scale());
}
```

- stripTrailingZeros() ensures that trailing zeros are not counted (e.g. `1.0` has 0 decimal places).
- `scale()` is more efficient than `String.indexOf()`.
- A negative `scale()` represents zero decimal places.

There you have it, the best of both worlds.

Comment: This might be wrong, because `10` becomes `1E1`  after `stripTrailingZeros()`, and then the `scale()` is `-1`, not `0`.

Comment: @EricWang The code uses `Math.max(0, ...)` so you will end up with `0` as expected.

Comment: Ok, didn't notice that .

Comment: This will fail when you construct BigDecimal using double value. e.g. `new BigDecimal(123.123).stripTrailingZeros().scale()` will return `46`.

Comment: @NandkumarTekale You shouldn't be using the `double` constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12218515/14731

Comment: if it's a `Double`, I would suggest you convert it to `String` then pass it to the `BigDecimal` constructor. i.e. `Math.max(0, BigDecimal(someDouble.toString()).stripTrailingZeros().scale())`.

Comment: @billydh Why? Would this add any precision? I can't see how it could.

Comment: Not for precision. it is to ensure the BigDecimal value is the same as the original Double value, e.g. `BigDecimal(123.123).stripTrailingZeros().scale()` returns 46 because `BigDecimal(123.123)` results in 123.12332127461876481476238467283 (just random number but you know what i mean). If we cast the Double value to String before passing to BigDecimal constructor, then it will result in the same value, e.g. 123.123.

Comment: @billydh It's not clear how you plan to cast a `double` to a `String` but if (for example) you use [Double.toString(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) then you will end up with the rounding rules mentioned in the Javadoc. There is no magic. You will end up with as little or as much precision as your binary representation had to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

Without having to convert to String, it should be more efficient to use the scale directly:

```
  private int getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(BigDecimal bigDecimal)
  {
    int scale =  bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().scale();
    return scale>0?scale:0;
  }
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. "." is not the only decimal separator in the world.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer by [Gili](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471139/6629569)...

Comment: yes, except that it's here since 2016 :-) and user1777653 has his answer already 2014

Answer (score 6):

That should do it

```
int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(BigDecimal number) {
    int scale = number.stripTrailingZeros().scale();
    return scale > 0 ? scale : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really get doubles i recommend formating them first as strings before creating the `BigDecimal`. At least that has worked for me: [How to check if a double has at most n decimal places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264937/how-to-check-if-a-double-has-at-most-n-decimal-places)

Depending on how many digits you expect you can either use standard formating like

```
String.valueOf(doubleValue);
```

or you could use specialised formatting to avoid exponential format

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
decimalFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
// don't use grouping for numeric-type cells
decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
value = decimalFormat.format(numericValue);
```

When you have a `BigDecimal` you can simply call `scale()` to get the number of decimal places.

Comment: The problem with scale() is that it fails to distinguish between decimal places and significant decimal places. It returns "1" for "1.0" when it should return 0, per the OP's request.

Answer (score 3):

It's not your code that's wrong, but your expectations. `double` is based on a binary floating point representation and completely unfit for accurately representing decimal fractions. Decimal 0.1 e.g. has an infinite number of digits when represented in binary, thus it gets truncated and when converted back to decimal, you get erros in the least significant digits.

If you use `BigDecimal` exclusively, your code will work as expected.

Comment: "If you use BigDecimal exclusively, your code will work as expected." --> ? But it doesn't work for my case.

Comment: @Yan: you're not using BigDecimal exclusively. You must not use any `double` or `float` values **including** any literals of those types.

Comment: @Yan: It does not work because you use double as your input parameter type. You have to avoid the use of double completely, because the second you put your decimal value into a double (even as an intermediate result), you have already corrupted it.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that even if the OP's code is converted to only use BigDecimals, it still won't work.  Why not?  Because it does not distinguish between decimal places and significant decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Math.floor(Math.log(x) / Math.log(10))
0.001 = -3
0.01  = -2
0.1   = -1  
1     = 0  
10    = 1  
100   = 2
```

Comment: This is helpful for getting the position of the first significant number in the value.

NB: But for values like 1.124 and I want to get the number of decimal places, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a look at the javadoc of BigDecimal. I'm not sure, but I'd give getScale and getPercision a try.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a BigDecimal with a specified number of decimal places is by using the setscale method over it.  Personally I like to also use the rounding version of the method (see the link below):
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20int)

If you're wanting to get the number of decimal positions that a BigDecimal is currently set at call the associated scale() method.

Comment: I am not interested in get "a BigDecimal with a specified number of decimal places". I am interested to know "a double with HOW MANY number of decimal places"

Comment: Ah....that's more of a problem.  The issue is that a double is imprecise.  For example, you may set the value of a double to 1.25 but when you look at it later the value returns as 1.24999999.  This is because of the way that Java stores it.  This kinda thing is why I avoid doubles as much as possible.

Comment: the description is correct, the example is not so good. 1.25 *can* be represented exactly in a `double`. 1.2 for example *can't*.

Comment: @Joachim  Yep...sorry.  I must be low on coffee today  :-).

Answer (score 0):

Best option I have found so far (not needing toString + index):

```
public static int digitsStripTrailingZero(BigDecimal value)
{
    return digits(value.stripTrailingZeros());
}

public static int digits(BigDecimal value)
{
    return Math.max(0, value.scale());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Michael Borgwardt answer is the correct one. As soon as you use any double or float, your values are already corrupted.

To provide a code example:

```
System.out.println("0 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("0")); // 0
System.out.println("1.0 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("1.0")); // 0
System.out.println("1.01 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(new BigDecimal("1.01"))); // 2
System.out.println("1.012 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace(new BigDecimal("1.012"))); // 3
System.out.println("0.01 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("0.01")); // 2
System.out.println("0.012 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("0.012")); // 3
System.out.println("0.00000000000000000012 = " + BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("0.00000000000000000012")); // 20
```

And an overloaded version of getNumberOfDecimalPlace so you could use it with BigDecimal or String:

```
public static int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(String value) {
    final int index = value.indexOf('.');
    if (index < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return value.length() - 1 - index;
}

public static int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(BigDecimal value) {
    return getNumberOfDecimalPlace(value.toPlainString());
}
```

Comment: You sure BigDecimalUtil.getNumberOfDecimalPlace("1.0")) going to return 0?

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it fails to distinguish between decimal places and significant decimal places.  As @Cheok rightly pointed out, it returns "1" for "1.0" when it should return 0, per the OP's request.

Answer (score -7):

Why not just change your code to get a doubles decimal places?

```
public static int getNumberOfDecimalPlace(double value) {
    //For whole numbers like 0
    if (Math.round(value) == value) return 0;
    final String s = Double.toString(value);
    System.out.println(s);
    final int index = s.indexOf('.');
    if (index < 0) {
       return 0;
    }
    return s.length() - 1 - index;
}
```

Comment: @Valentin: Because the use of double is the fundamental problem. This is a step into exactly the wrong direction.

Comment: It does not work for double with large number of decimal places, for example 0.0000000000000000000000000000001. Double.toString(double) will return 1.0E-31. Your whole logic fails

Comment: okay, it didn't see it that way at first (I'm not the answerer, I was  just wondering :))

Comment: @Michael ok, fine. No need for a downvote though as it was just a sugguestion. He seems to be passing doubles to it. And based on other comments it seemed like he just wanted the decimal places of the double value.

Comment: I accept your answer because you are the only who follow my requirement. I make an amendment, by using 
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.########"); final String s = decimalFormat.format(value);