# Unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor

Tags: java

I started using Sonar recently in a project, and i got a PMD rule broken about using the constructor `new BigDecimal(double val)`. When i read the java documentation, i found that new BigDecimal(double val) is somewhat unpredictable and that I should use `new BigDecimal(String val)` which is predictable.

Here is what javadoc says for `BigDecimal` `public BigDecimal(double val)`:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal
>   representation of the double's binary floating-point value. The scale
>   of the returned BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10scale ×
>   val) is an integer.
>
> Notes:
>
> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
>   might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a
>   `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1,
>   with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
>
> The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:
>   writing `new BigDecimal("0.1")` creates a `BigDecimal` which is
>   exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is generally
>   recommended that the String constructor be used in preference to this
>   one.
>
> When a double must be used as a source for a `BigDecimal`, note that
>   this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the
>   same result as converting the double to a String using the
>   `Double.toString(double)` method and then using the
>   `BigDecimal(String)` constructor. To get that result, use the static
>   `valueOf(double)` method.

Why does this constructor really exists? Isnt `new BigDecimal(String val)` enough for that matter? When should I use the `new BigDecimal(double val)` constructor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why does this constructor really exists?

It converts the actual represented value of `double` to a BigDecimal.  The whole point of BigDecimal is to give as much precision as possible and that is what this constructor does.

If you want to take the value you would get with a small amount of rounding the `Double.toString(double)` uses you can use

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1));
```

prints

```
0.1
```

> When should I use the new BigDecimal(double val) constructor

When you want to know the value `double` really represents.  You can apply your own rounding as required.

When you use `double` you should always apply a sensible rounding.  But, if you did that you may find you don't need BigDecimal. ;)

Answer (score 7):

`When should I use the new BigDecimal(double val) constructor?`

Preferably - nowhere.

If you are willing to play with BigDecimals, using constructor with double means loosing all benefits of exact number presentation.

`Why does this constructor really exists?`

Because sometimes you have only double, that you want to translate to BigDecimal. Forcing you to use `.toString()` inbetween would be just silly ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because if you already begin with a `double` value as data, you have already lost that precission. So not having it would force you to convert it to `String` for `BigDecimal` to convert it back.

And also, maybe sometimes you just need **that** value.

Comment: So, if i`m working with a double value, and convert to string, then to bigdecimal, i loose precision? Using for instance Double.toString?

Comment: You do, because Double.toString() is a tricky beast. It doesn't really return the exact value of the double you're passing to it. instead, it returns the shortest string that, when parsed, will still be converted to exactly the specified double value. That's a bit confusing, but basically, it means that if Double.toString(0.100000000000000005551115123) is "0.1", then it is guaranteed that Double.parseDouble("0.1") is also 0.100000000000000005551115123. And this tricky thing is why you lose precision, but it never looks like it does when you print your double value to the console.

Comment: The loss of precision occurs because new BigDecimal(Double.toString(0.1d)), really represents the exact "0.1" value, even though 0.1d is not really equal to 0.1 (since it really is 0.100000000000000005551115123). In some cases that behavior could be desirable, but in some others, it is an unacceptable loss of precision.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the double constructor when the data you want to work with already exists as a double value. Having to convert it to a string before converting it to BigDecimal would be a wasteful in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Unpredictable? I disagree.

```
final double before = 0.1;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(before);
double after = bd.doubleValue();
assert before == after;
```

Key to understanding:

```
assert 0.1 == 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625;
```

If you truly meant "0.1", then yes, use the String constructor =) But if you have a `double` already, then that double is not "0.1".

The JavaDoc you quoted says:

> When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that
>   this constructor provides an **exact** conversion;

I fail to see how an exact conversion is "unpredictable" and I am very much in favor of removing the word "must" from this quote.

At the end of the day, both constructors work just like intended. If you have String "0.1", then BigDecimal(String) convert this value exactly. If you have a double 0.1, then BigDecimal(double) convert this value exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
double val = 0.1; // this is not 0.1, but an approximination as pointed out in other answers.
BigDecimal biggy = new BigDecimal(val); // this variable conatains the "same" value as val does, however it is not 0.1, but as pointed out in other answers: 0.100000000000000005551115123`
```

So, in the case listed here, where you have full control over the source code, you should write the *val* as 'String val = "0.1"'

However the contructor `BigDecimal(double val)` is usefull in case you read binary doubles from a file. Obviously you will want in nearly all cases BigDecimals that are exactly the same as the 'doubles'