# Operations with BigDecimal and double in Java

Tags: java, variables, double, bigdecimal

I am trying to use Advogadro's number (6.022*10^23) in a java program and i use BigDecimal variable to store it. However i want to multiply it with an int or a double and still keep the precision, but it throws an error!

```
bad operand types for binary operator '*'
  first type:  double
  second type: BigDecimal
```

Is there any simple way to do that? Also is there a way to print the result in scientific notation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read the javadoc for BigDecimal?

Comment: Please provide your code how you do it

Comment: Avogadro's number known precision is 5.0×10–8 (http://www.quickiwiki.com/en/Avogadro_constant), so it can be perfectly represented by `double` type, no need to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Sorry, but there are no operator overloading in Java.

Comment: What is the purpose of trying to "keep the precision"? double carries 53 significant bits, about 15.9 significant digits. The Avogadro constant is known to about 8 significant digits. For a reasonably numerically stable calculation, the measurement error far exceeds the double precision rounding error. 6.022e23 is a 4 significant digit approximation to the measured value. The rounding error you are choosing to accept by using that approximation dwarfs even the measurement error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Operations are only supported for primitive types (and + for Strings)

BigDecimals has implemented the operations as functions.

you can only uses BigDecimals for operations with BigDecimals. So you need to convert your double value:

```
BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(doubleValue).multiply(factor2);
```

Comment: ok, but if i want to apply it to something big, like a formula i will have to do it like this: 

BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(doubleValue).multiply(factor2).divide(factor3).add(5.7); (for example)

Comment: @AngeloUknown Unless you really need more precision than double allows, which is unusual for calculations involving physically measured quantities, you would be better off just working in double with infix operators.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the double into a `BigDecimal` first:

```
BigDecimal result = yourBigDecimal.multiply(new BigDecimal(yourDouble));
```

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal is not a primitive type. So you really cannot apply simple maths (*,-,+) into that. It has many methods in order to support all the basic mathematics. You can use them. As comment suggest read the java doc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

What big decimal has is a two main parts. One part contains the number, and the second part precision. So if you want to handle special maths which is not standard available you can get those two values separately and try with higher mathematical algorithms

Quate from java doc :

> 21/110 = 0.190 // integer=190, scale=3

Answer (score 0):

Do sthg like this;

```
 public class Payment
 {
     BigDecimal itemCost;
     BigDecimal totalCost; // You can initialize it if you wish.

     public BigDecimal calculateCost(int itemQuantity, BigDecimal itemPrice)
     {
         itemCost  = itemPrice.multiply(new BigDecimal(itemQuantity));
         totalCost = totalCost.add(itemCost);
         return totalCost;
     }
 }
```

And read javadoc for BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: [Unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218515/unpredictability-of-the-bigdecimaldouble-constructor)

new Bigdecimal(myDouble) is wrong.
You have to use Bigdecimal.valueOf(myDouble) instead.

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal multi = BigDecimal.valueOf(doubleValue).multiply(bigDecimal)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Multiply would be right..
To do (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=) operations, you can use compareTo of BigDecimal..
resulting in 0,1,-1.
I hope this too helps.. ;)