# BigDecimal Rounding incorrectly

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I was expecting this code:

```
    double valore = 20.775;

    BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(valore);
    c = c.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);


    System.out.println(c.doubleValue());
```

to return 20.78, but it's returning 20.77 instead.

Is it an error? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218515/unpredictability-of-the-bigdecimaldouble-constructor)

Comment: BigDecimal is rounding correctly. You are using doubleValue(),  which causes the incorrectness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is correct.
 You can read some high-level details in [another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218515/unpredictability-of-the-bigdecimaldouble-constructor) or read more in [documentation to BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

It is not common to use `BigDecimal` constructor with `double` param, because it will exactly represent what is inside `double`.
So when you write: `new BigDecimal(20.775)` you are not necessarily have 20.775 as a result (rather you will have something like `20.77499999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`)

For you to test:
1) testing BigDecimal representation
a) `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(20.775));` => `20.77499999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`
b) `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("20.775"));` => `20.775`

2) test rounding with different `BigDecimal` constructors:
a) `new BigDecimal(20.775)` after rounding half up will show 20.77.
b) `new BigDecimal("20.775")` after rounding half up will show 20.78.
c) `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(20.775)` after rounding half up will show 20.78.

So as a conclusion:
Do not use `BigDecimal` constructor with `double` param.
Instead use `BigDecimal` constructor with `String` param.

Hope it helps