# Handling the "BigDecimal(double) should not be used" bug reported by SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, bigdecimal

SonarQube reports **any** occurrence of the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor as a bug.  The [description](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2111) of this rule refers to the note #1 in [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) that says *"The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable"*; but in the JavaDoc there is also the note #3: *"When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion"* that is very important IMHO and it's ignored by SonarQube.

The description provides this non-compliant example:

```
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(1.1);
```

and I fully agree with it, but let's consider a case like this one:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(123.45));
```

It is reported as a bug by SonarQube just like the previous one but I think it should be marked as a false positive because this use case refers to note #3 of the JavaDoc.

The description from SonarQube also refers to [this page](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/x/kzdGBQ)  but it provides a different rule that says *"Do not construct BigDecimal objects from floating-point literals"*: it is more restrictive and it applies to the first example but not to the second one.

So the question is: should we mechanically change any occurrence of `BigDecimal(double)` as suggested by SonarQube?  I guess no but [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/#:%7E:text=For%20Code%20Smells%20and%20Bugs%2C%20zero%20false%2Dpositives%20are%20expected.) says *"For Code Smells and Bugs, zero false-positives are expected"* and I'm surprised that SonarQube is so misleading on this use case.

Finally note that `BigDecimal(double)` in the context of SonarQube is discussed also in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218515/unpredictability-of-the-bigdecimaldouble-constructor) but my question is quite different.

Comment: I think it's an issue of indeterminate precision and probably should be addressed. I would just format the double as a string with a fixed number of decimal places and construct BigDecimal with that.

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for moral support or what. If you want the messages to stop you've got to get rid of BigDecimal(double) constructor calls.

Comment: #3 is a warning. Most times people don't want an exact conversion.

Comment: @president-james-k-polk, I'm not searching for moral support: I just want to understand whether my assumption that it is a false positive is correct or not.

Comment: @Bohemian, so we should *never* use that constructor? Not even when the source is not a floating-point literal?