# How to check number of digits from BigDecimal?

Tags: java

The requirement is to check if the number of digits is less than 7 digits in that case insert in DB else don't. I have tried the following solutions:

First solution:

```
public static void checkNoOfDigitVal(BigDecimal bigDecVal) {
    BigInteger digits = bigDecVal.toBigInteger();
    BigInteger ten = BigInteger.valueOf(10);
    int count = 0;
    do {
        digits = digits.divide(ten);
        count++;
    } while (!digits.equals(BigInteger.ZERO));
    System.out.println("Number of digits : " + count);
}
```

First solution works fine sometimes but sometimes the condition in while loop is not satisfied and it keeps on increasing the count number leading to endless count.

Second solution:

```
public static void checkNoOfDigitsVal(BigDecimal bigDecVal) {
    String string = bigDecVal.toString();
    String[] splitedString = string.split("\\.");
    String[] newVal = splitedString[0].split("");
    int a = newVal.length - 1;
    if (a <= 6) {
        System.out.println("correct size insert into DB: " + a);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect size insert cancel: " + a);
    }
}
```

For example, if the value is `999999.9999`, the second solution will return `newVal.length = 6`.

Please suggest a better solution to check the number of digits for big decimal where looping overhead can be minimized.

Comment: What happens if you do this? `while (!digits.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0);`.

Comment: *"the second solution will return newVal.length = 7 instead it should be 6 which is incorrect"* Huh? Is 6 correct or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296110/determine-number-of-decimal-place-using-bigdecimal

Comment: `String[] newVal = splitedString[0].split(""); int a = newVal.length;`? why not just `splitedString[0].length()`?

Comment: Though @Alnitak has given a great answer, I just wonder why would you want to do the decision based on "no of digits before decimal point", instead of a simple `final BigDecimal LIMIT = new BigDecimal("1_000_000"); .... if (yourValue.compareTo(LIMIT) < 0) { doYourThing();}` ?

Comment: @AdrianShum that would indeed appear to be a good solution to the "more than 6 digits requirement" :p

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get it trivially using:

```
static int integerDigits(BigDecimal n) {
    n = n.stripTrailingZeros();
    return n.precision() - n.scale();
}
```

The precision is the total number of digits, and the scale is how many of those are to the right of the decimal point, so the difference is how many are to the *left* of the decimal point.

**EDIT** it's necessary to remove any trailing zeros to get a correct result for e.g. `0.000`

**EDIT 2** alternatively (and acks to @AdrianShum), since the problem with trailing zeroes only manifests itself with `0.00...` you could use:

```
static int integerDigits(BigDecimal n) {
    return n.signum() == 0 ? 1 : n.precision() - n.scale();
}
```

Live demo at http://ideone.com/uI6iMG

Comment: I'd rather simply do a `return (n.signum() == 0) ? 1 : ( n.precision() - n.scale());` to avoid extra work and temp object for stripping zeros

Comment: @AdrianShum yeah, that works too :)   It does only appear to be 0.00...  that causes the problem with `.scale()` and trailing zeroes.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak for providing the great answer. Your piece of code has reduced the lines of code and looks very efficient. Bravo!!!

Comment: The precision is not the total number of digits in case of leading zeros. `integerDigits(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.00000123456))` will return `-5`! Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56355974/883603) for a more robust solution.

Comment: @Dormouse - The above *seems* to work just fine with leading zeros: https://ideone.com/epmPsN Can you provide an example of where it's failing?

Comment: NOTE: precision and scale can be equal, please consider a case:
new BigDecimal("0.32")
scale = 2
precision = 2

Answer (score 4):

There's a **much** better solution in [Alnitak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792782/157247), posted just after mine (but which I've only seen now). I guess I'll leave this since a couple of people have found it useful, but if I needed to do this, I'd use their approach, not the approach below.

---

Your second solution is close, but it doesn't have to be quite that complicated:

```
public static void checkNoOfDigitsVal(BigDecimal bigDecVal) {
    String str = bigDecVal.toString();
    int wholeNumberLength = str.split("\\.")[0].length();
    if (wholeNumberLength <= 6) {
        System.out.println("correct size insert into DB: " + wholeNumberLength);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect size insert cancel: " + wholeNumberLength);
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/qg9VHO)

I'm assuming that your `999999.999` example should result in `wholeNumberLnegth` of `6` and therefore be inserted in the DB (the question is unclear about that).

Answer (score 1):

Because the current answers are not robust enough IMO, Here's my solution.
This method will scale a `BigDecimal` to the given length, but only scales the fractional part. It will throw an Exception if the integer part will be scaled. For my use case this is what I want. Tweak it to your liking.

```
public static BigDecimal scaleBigDecimalToLength(BigDecimal bigDecimal, int length) throws NumbersUtilException {
  int digitCount = bigDecimal.toPlainString().replaceAll("[.,-]", "").length();
  if (digitCount > length) {
      int scale = bigDecimal.scale();
      int newScale = length - (digitCount - scale);
      if (scale > 0 && newScale >= 0) {
          bigDecimal = bigDecimal
                  .setScale(length - (digitCount - scale), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      } else {
          throw new NumbersUtilException(
                  String.format("Cannot scale %s to a length of %s", bigDecimal, length));
    }
  }
  return bigDecimal;
}
```

`scaleBigDecimalToLength(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0000012345600000), 8)` 
Output: 0.0000012

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to ignore the Dot (".") and count. then try this :

```
        int count = 0;
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("123.1000");

        String[] split = bigDecimal.toString()
                .split("\\.");

        for (String element : split) {
            count = count + element.length();
        }

        System.out.println("Total digits are " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you have a method, like:

```
int countDigitsBeforeDecimalPoint(BigDecimal n)
```

To get the number of digits before the decimal place, use this body:

```
return n.toBigInteger().abs().toString().length();
```

Or, if you want to use precision and scale - with subtracting them you always get a correct result, except the value is between -1 and 1 (exclusive), so this also works to count only numbers (no sign):

```
return n.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == -1 && n.compareTo(new BigDecimal("-1")) == 1 ? 1 : n.precision() - n.scale();
```

If you also need to include the minus sign, then you should do it differently:

```
return StringUtils.substringBefore(n.toPlainString(), ".").length()
```

If you don't want to use Apache commons StringUtils, it get's a bit more weird:

```
String s = n.toPlainString();
int i = (i = s.indexOf('.')) > -1 ? i : s.length();
return s.substring(0, i).length();
```

I tried several Unit test, for those I could not find a number that does not work. Still of course, any improvements welcome!

PS: a shorter way to include minus sign in count with standard Java:

```
return n.toPlainString().length() - (n.scale() > 0 ? (n.scale() + 1) : 0);
```