# Best way to check minor unit of BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, validation, decimal, bigdecimal

I have a minor unit setup for amounts, which is: 0.01

It means the amounts are allowed to have maximum 2 decimals.

What could be the best and easiest validation check in Java for these examples:

- 5 --> valid
- 5.0 --> valid
- 5.00 --> valid
- 5.000 --> valid
- 5.1 --> valid
- 5.11 --> valid
- 5.111 --> NOT valid
- 5.110 --> valid

Code should be something like:

```
public void isValid(BigDecimal amountToCheck, BigDecimal minorUnit) {
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `BigDecimal minorUnit`? Does the value of `0.01` change? If yes, why BigDecimal and not a simple `int` specifying how many decimal places there can be?

Comment: These are good questions, but the thing is that this is how they implemented here where I work the minor unit thingy, so I need to get a solution by this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest part of this answer is taken from [Determine Number of Decimal Place using BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296110/determine-number-of-decimal-place-using-bigdecimal).

So basically you have one method giving you the number of decimals (excluding trailing `0` decimals) :

```
int getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
    String string = bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
    int index = string.indexOf(".");
    return index < 0 ? 0 : string.length() - index - 1;
}
```

Then you call it to fit your needs :

```
public boolean isValid(BigDecimal amountToCheck, BigDecimal minorUnit) {

    return getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(amountToCheck) <= getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(minorUnit);
}
```

Or as the comment by @Pijotrek suggests :

```
public boolean isValid(BigDecimal amountToCheck, int maxDecimals ) {

    return getNumberOfDecimalPlaces(amountToCheck) <= maxDecimals;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the inefficient conversion to `String` and searching, just `.stripTrailingZeros().scale()`